# Can you change the text colour of a specific part of a Material UI TextField?

Tags: css, material-ui

There is no guidance on how to change the text colour of part of these inputs https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/

Say I want to make the text alternate between two different colors. Is that possible?

Comment: you should be able to change it using `color`. For example, `color: red`

Comment: I believe that makes the whole thing red. Can I make some words red and some word black, for example?

Comment: for that, you need to split the words and place them into its specific tags. For example,

`<span class="red">this text is red 
   <span class="green">This green color inside red</span>  
</span>
<span class="blue">this is blue</span>`


and then in the CSS
`.red {color: red;} 
span.green { color: green; } 
.blue {color: blue;}
`